# Merge conflict when running 'git rebase'

Tags: git

I am on a developer branch, and I try to execute `git rebase remote/a_remote_branch`
I see:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: change #1
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 change #1
```

My question is why is `git rebase` trying to apply 'change #1'?

This is because when I do `git log`, I see 'change #1' in my local branch, why git trying to apply 'change #1' again when I rebase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between `merge` and `rebase` is that `rebase` is trying to make it look like you *based* your branch on a newer version of the parent branch.  So it removes all of your branch commits, fast-forwards to the the latest parent commit, and then tries to re-apply your changes.  Hence re-*basing*.  If you `merge` it makes a new commit that pulls in all of the parent changes *on top* of your work.  Then the conflicts (if any) will be in that merge commit rather than in your existing branch work.

Comment: If I check out a remote branch like this "git check -b aBranch remote/aBranch", I am tracking 'remote/aBranch', right? My question is if someone 'rebase remote/aBranch', will I able to tell from "git log"?

Comment: @michael: Rebasing isn't appropriate for branches that other people can see.  It rewrites history, which causes havoc for other people who are working in the same tree.  Rebasing is useful when your project will eventually be submitted back as a patchset (and then the branch will be defunct) rather than when you will be able to `git push` directly.